# PCB via with 50 ohm characteristic impedance

Tags: pcb-design, signal-integrity, via

To get specific characteristic impedance on PCB track we have to have carefully controlled distance from GND, PCB track width and track height. OK, clear.

With via the issue is that it is not referenced to GND since it is a vertical signal path. Also, its dimensions are not same as the PCB track, the signal path is a circular conductor inside the via. How then do engineers ensure that a via is 50 ohm as well, to match it with the PCB track to ensure signal integrity.

Comment: At high frequencies you include a ground via when you change layers. At lower frequencies the via will be too short to matter.

Comment: yes, this question is about high speed signals. Following the way we get specific characteristic impedance from stripline or microstrip, I am sure that the number, location and position of the GND vias near the signal via will matter a lot. I am not aware of any detail though.

Comment: There is also another thing that needs to be considered. What if the via length is actually less than the wavelength of the high speed signal?

Comment: Also, for a via in a multi-layer board, its impedance (by reducing the capacitance) will change if the unused unconnected pads are simply removed rather than left along the barrel.

Answer (score 1):

There are some formulas to estimate the impedance of via.

When via impedance really matters, engineers use 3D EM field simulation programs that can show the impedance, when you give it the PCB details (stackup, material, etc) and the via details (pad sizes, distances to ground plane, on each layer of PCB).

Comment: These so called 3D field solvers should be ubiquitous in this era of high speed digital electronics.

Comment: Shouldn't the via impedance matter when the PCB track impedance matters as well?

Comment: When the impedance of a transmission line matters, it applies to both the tracks and vias, as well as connector PCB footprints, PCB footprints of any other component on the transmission line, connectors themselves, and cabling.

Comment: ok, lets assume that we have DDR4 connecting to a microprocessor. The PCB tracks must be specific impedance and length matched. The track Z is a function of dielectric, distance from (continuos) reference plane, copper weight and track width. This much is clear. But the presentations do not dwell on via impedance topic. They just say put some stictching via to ground near the signal via. It gives impression that the via can be any size, just out GND via near it. But won't this introduce signal integrity problem and cause design failure due to Z mismatch?

Comment: Usually via impedance is not talked much. Yes, it will cause a mismatch. If poorly or wrongly designed, it may cause failures. If even adequately designed, it might be OK. It does not need to be perfectly designed to pass, it must be just good enough with some margin of error and tolerance to pass.

Comment: I see, so how does one decide the signal via size (pad and hole) and stitching via size (pad and hole) and the distance between the signal via and the one or more stitching vias?

Comment: Either with very approximate formulas found on the subject, or using a hideously expensive modeling software to simulate it.

Comment: How do the professionals do it when they are designing PCBs that contain DDR3, DDR4 and/or PICe Gen 4 tracks? I thought 3D solvers would be standard by now and not "niche" anymore.